# Incorporating git with visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, git

Im a 3rd year uni student in information technology. Im due to hand in an assignment which is pretty much completed. The assignment is on creating an enrollment system for a small university where students can register, choose modules etc

**My Question**

We are instructed to incorporate Git bundles into the vb project.

- What exactly is git? As very little info is given on the topic
- How do I incorporate Git into my visual basic program?
- **Most importantly** What benefits are there for incorporating Git bundles into a VB
  project, and what can I do with it?

Comment: You really ought to be asking your instructor about this; I don't think they'd appreciate you running to a website like SO to give you all the answers. Failing that, have you tried searching with Google?

Comment: I have tried using google not much help there, Im doing open distance learning so I cant contact my lecturer

Comment: If your instructor is completely inaccessible (via email, phone, IM or things the school provides like message boards), then either they or your university have completely failed. Have you *really* not been able to find *any* information by typing "what is git" into Google?

Comment: I can contact my lecture its just that there is a huge time difference between us, all I want to know is what does git allow you to do in vb.net? The module is on vb.net but we are supposed to use git with it which provides very little information in the description on the module

Comment: First, learn what git is. Then consider how you can apply that to the development of *any* program (not putting it inside the program, but as a tool in the development process).

Comment: #1 on google results: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGit_(software)&ei=5_0ZU8DbAuS52wWTkICQDQ&usg=AFQjCNF-3SEMy2Sve5Ptar_OR-42U87AdA&sig2=kUckvXOhIOaUi6AdP-Awig&bvm=bv.62578216,d.b2I

Comment: Listen all im asking is i want to zip my project in a git bundle everything im doing acccording to instructions in windows cmd line but when I do git status it tells me git is not recognizable as an internal or external command. Please help me on this one im doing everything as per lecturer instruction but it wont zip the git bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a distributed version control and source code management system.  There is a ton of information on it that is widely available.

From your comment "*when I do git status it tells me git is not recognizable as an internal or external command*", it sounds like you do not have Git installed.

Read through this post:  [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide).

It seems like you are looking for a quick, 5 minute fix.  Truth is, there isn't one.  Git is a very powerful tool that will prove to be invaluable over the course of your studies/career.  The link I posted will help you to install Git correctly and get your command line instructions to operate successfully, but I highly recommend taking the time to learn the tool.  Git has literally had the largest impact on my career and many others as well.